# 15 months at job, admittedly being underpaid by supervisors. No raise expected for 6-8 months due to budget. What points should I address in followup?

Tags: raise

Been with the company 15 months in an expanding capacity since I first started working, new duties and responsibilities etc. Supervisors have agreed that I'm being underpaid, but cannot increase compensation for some time. What are some points I should bring up for a followup meeting?

Comment: What is your goal in this followup meeting?  What is your goal overall?  Perhaps it makes sense to identify non-financial benefits the company can offer and ask for those in lieu of an immediate raise.  Perhaps it makes sense to play hardball in demanding a raise at the risk of being let go.  Perhaps it makes sense to accept the situation in the meeting and look for opportunities elsewhere.  Depends on your goals

Comment: are you intending to push for a raise despite being told it's over budget?

Comment: What is the nature of the "followup meeting"?

Comment: I don't have a concrete goal at this time, the one on one is a scheduled thing for general purporses. The budgets operated on a fiscal calendar, I wouldn't expect any raise until 6 to 8 months. I enjoy working for this company and the work I do, but I'm not sure if I should expect anything more than their word. Should I request documentation guaranteeing an increase in pay or other such items?

Comment: If they don't have the money now, why not let you 'loan' them the difference (with interest) until they do have it? Not really a serious answer, but IMO that would be a reasonable response

Answer (score 0):

If you were told that there is no more money for the next 6-to-8 months, what do you expect to happen as a result of this follow up meeting. They will print money or they go digging for lost treasure to pay you what you are worth ? Be realistic. You do not need a meeting. You need the hiring authority to promise you a pay raise for the day, they get new funding for personnel. And they need to put a number for this. If you don;t like it, you can walk 
away today or when you have a better offer. It is pretty cut and dry.

Decide if you can live with the money you are making, doing what you are doing today, for the next 6-8 months. Obviously, nothing is changing till then.

Answer (score 0):

If the company is good enough for you to stay at, without the raise, then just continue to prove that you deserve one as soon as there is space in the budget. Lay out all the new responsibilities you've taken on and how you've grown and improved as an employee. Hopefully they will recognise your worth and compensate you nicely for the time you've been without a raise. There isn't a guarantee of this though.

If you can't live with no raise for 6-8 months then **brush up your CV and look for other jobs**. If they don't have the budget to pay you more... well they don't have the budget! Nothing you say in a meeting is likely to change that.

Another option (depending on the company) is asking for compensation in equity, but that may not be something you're interested in, or you may not think it's worth it (especially if the company is struggling financially)